# How can I make Haproxy don't send SNI field to backend server?

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

Following reverse proxy work for en.wikipedia.org but not zh.wikipedia.org, my censor prevents access to zh.wikipedia.org by SNI. if no SNI then just correct IP in /etc/hosts is enough.

*Original configuration:*

```
defaults
    log 127.0.0.1:514 user
    timeout connect 5000s
    timeout client 5000s
    timeout server 5000s
listen reverse-proxy
    bind 127.0.0.1:443
    mode tcp
    balance static-rr
    server srv1 208.80.153.224
```

---

Following reverse proxy cause Firefox say:

> This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that
>   Firefox may only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not
>   possible to add an exception for this certificate.

*Changed configuration:*

```
global
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
defaults
    log 127.0.0.1:514 user
    timeout connect 5000s
    timeout client 5000s
    timeout server 5000s
listen reverse-proxy
    bind 127.0.0.1:443 ssl crt /home/test/wiki.pem
    mode http
    http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=16000000; includeSubDomains; preload;"
    balance static-rr
    server srv1 208.80.153.224 ssl verify none
```

Comment: Please don't make such radical changes to your question, you are invalidating existing answers. Either add your new configuration  below, and mark it clearly as a new configuration, or accept the answer and create a new question with your new configuration.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I'm sorry for my bad, can you tell me edit this question vs do accept the answer then create a new question, which is better?

Comment: This has been diskussed here: https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5697/should-follow-up-questions-be-asked-in-comments-or-on-their-own

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[As drookie said](https://serverfault.com/a/957336/485358), TCP mode can't do this, but **in Haproxy the HTTP mode doesn't send SNI field by default.**
The line `http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=16000000; includeSubDomains; preload;"` don't make sense.(you can delete it in this case)
**This real problem source is the browser configuration as it rejects all unknown issuer by default**

**WARNING: The following workaround will disable HSTS entirely, but you can use [the HTTPS Everywhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/https-everywhere/) to get similar security.**
In Firefox open `about:config` then [change `network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist` to `false`](https://superuser.com/a/1303717/890315), this reverse work as except.
[Also, you might need to delete SiteSecurityServiceState.txt in your Firefox to clear HSTS information in your Firefox.](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/clear-hsts-settings-chrome-firefox/)

**WARNING: Don't use the CA certificate way if you can't verify your backend server**
if you don't want to use browser extension then [create one CA certificate for you then make your browser trust your CA certificate](https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/).

Comment: **WARNING: This will disable HSTS entirely.** HSTS makes sense whether it's related to the problem or not. Please do not suggest breaking browser security features.

Answer (score 2):

In this configuration you cannot, because you're using `mode tcp` proxying, so your haproxy's just transparently passing the entire HTTP session to the backend. You should switch to the `mode http` and manipulate headers.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you see my edit and say how make `mode http` work?