# How can I verify Haproxy backend HTTPS server as in browser I can?

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

Haproxy's documentation says the [ssl](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#ssl%20(Server%20and%20default-server%20options)) and the [verify](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#verify%20%28Server%20and%20default-server%20options%29) server option enable verify on backend server's certificate via one [ca-file](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#ca-file%20(Server%20and%20default-server%20options)) but I try to use Firefox export the backend server's CA file then use the exported CA file to verify backend server and I get the `503 Service Unavailable` prompt.
**Why the CA file and SSL verify doesn't work?**

[Note the simplest TCP mode reverse proxy not helpful in this case because I don't want to send the SNI information.](https://serverfault.com/a/957418/485358)

Answer (score 0):

**Why the CA file and SSL verify doesn't work?**
The reason is you export the CA file as `X.509 Certificate (PEM)`, that is not the correct CA file.
You must use the [ca-file](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#ca-file%20(Server%20and%20default-server%20options)) server option with the correct CA file.
Use Browser(Firefox) Export website certificate save as `X.509 Certificate with chain(PEM)` to get the correct CA file.
For example `server wikipedia-server 208.80.153.224 ssl verify required ca-file /path/to/*wikipediaorg.crt`